# Vagrant Master and Slave Boxes - SSH Key setup

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to setup ssh key login, so I can type `ssh slave01` without password to ssh into the slave machine, but I'm having trouble setting it up here. The master and slave are Vagrant boxes running Ubuntu.

The master box has the following settings

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ifconfig
          ...
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat /etc/hosts
...
192.168.33.10 master
192.168.33.12 slave01
192.168.33.13 slave02

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/.ssh$ cat id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDWx6Zj6BLkd/Dz1ZY/YdzeHC6LGhx+bCdciYerm7q2x7DEAerbdFEsU68Dugso5PbROVCs68fCkVRdNeD7sAzgU0F8MFXRaiWGJNE8TM4NpzaiVDsiVd0V7334YM3hdFmD9uEshh3avIhzqbogtx0gHGerwizAyoVIaOC/OZKhd4GgBuUZchGB569s0Y2D4RYERA004OtGxSo1WzFmwIx64SS4bKF1Y/mKxRaU+aDuZMsO5CpsJ/KSKuBsqL1CX3ygupgivulYENYkWiCnm9R4o/jLDutpmOekm4Es0TdfaXo5m8Xu3kLYd0sk4LjAmSFw05waa7dmpGm+KIRHGDWx vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
```

The slave the following settings

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ifconfig
...
          inet addr:192.168.33.12  Bcast:192.168.33.255  
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC1hp+ytnJJ1r2qCHdX/t6HZoewGj+NyMDZY90udyXG7h58b2rHorT3XtIu2OB+r5mdiMFsXqTUIa+gSjU6LijMsEzaP4GpRmN8BgGzFyXYrX6LtCCKNBAVjtPTuyObKmvRihtTeN3ZkvDdwGKXgVqbGdqjyHQc/1WfV+mMKa5p7mSqesVZfhs2behvnrGfXsu5C8Us8oHcr13Qpm9fHIWT+F+kPlOeOfrIaMpg9pY3sd4YHhziLjwKZkpmZhQTT7pgqI2ySCEiZQRRQV5VMdnv/HvHcAmi83S7fgSJqCMu4e/Hw0QxkKnJlzE93ornRMbFy8t6IeOH8gwsMtoqyUxd vagrant

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDWx6Zj6BLkd/Dz1ZY/YdzeHC6LGhx+bCdciYerm7q\
2x7DEAerbdFEsU68Dugso5PbROVCs68fCkVRdNeD7sAzgU0F8MFXRaiWGJNE8TM4NpzaiVDsiVd0V73\
34YM3hdFmD9uEshh3avIhzqbogtx0gHGerwizAyoVIaOC/OZKhd4GgBuUZchGB569s0Y2D4RYERA004\
OtGxSo1WzFmwIx64SS4bKF1Y/mKxRaU+aDuZMsO5CpsJ/KSKuBsqL1CX3ygupgivulYENYkWiCnm9R4\
o/jLDutpmOekm4Es0TdfaXo5m8Xu3kLYd0sk4LjAmSFw05waa7dmpGm+KIRHGDWx vagrantvagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
```

When I run the following from the command line in Master, it is keep asking for the password. I am not sure why it is doing this.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/.ssh$ ssh slave01
vagrant@slave01's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
vagrant@slave01's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
vagrant@slave01's password:
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ssh-copy-id` to move your ssh key between machines. You likely did not set the proper `chmod` permissions on the directories.